# losing data when zipping files

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I am using rubyzip on windows to zip up a directory.
When I unzip the archive some of the files are smaller than they were.

Zipping should be a lossless operation so I am wondering why this is happening.

Here is the code I am using:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'find'
require 'zip/zip'

output = "c:/temp/test.zip"
zos = Zip::ZipOutputStream.new(output)

path = "C:/temp/profile"
::Find.find(path) do |file|
  next if File.directory?(file)
  entry = file.sub("#{path}/", '')

  zos.put_next_entry(entry)
  zos << File.read(file)
end
zos.close
```

The specific files that are having an issue are from a firefox profile. cert8.db and key3.db

Running the same code under jruby on linux with the same files works as expected - all the files are the same size.

Any ideas why this is a problem on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is that you are reading files as text, not as binary files. These two fundamental modes of reading files have difference in such things as linebreaks, symbols EOF, etc.

Try `File.open(file,'rb'){|f|f.read}` instead of `File.read(file)`.

Comment: +1 Windows needs to know about binary files. For safety the "b" should be there.